# mongo replica failing to sync and start with replicaset

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3 node replicas mongo cluster. I managed to start first two nodes but the thrd one it's failing with:

```
[rsBackgroundSync] starting rollback: OplogStartMissing our last op time fetched: (term: 33, timestamp: Jan 22 09:34:52:1). source's GTE: (term: 34, timestamp: Jan 22 09:35:25:1) hashes: (-9060984734961038872/2476820215102251535)
2017-01-22T14:01:51.206+0000 F REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] need to rollback, but in inconsistent state
2017-01-22T14:01:51.206+0000 I -        [rsBackgroundSync] Fatal assertion 28723 UnrecoverableRollbackError need to rollback, but in inconsistent state. minvalid: (term: 38, timestamp: Jan 22 11:13:01:1) > our last optime: (term: 33, timestamp: Jan 22 09:34:52:1) @ 18750
```

I made a mongodump from Primary and remove this third replica (mongoreplica3) from the replicaset and restore it, but after I tried to set back the node ion replica set it's still failing with the same error.

Any idea how can I manually sync and start this mongoreplica3 with my replicaset?

Comment: I tried to dig around understand the error. Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by removing everything from /data and start the mongoreplica which got synced with the Primary after.

Comment: Hi, I want to know, the  '/data" path you mentioned above,  is the dbpath in the config file?

"dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb" ,  My replica node had a similar "18750 UnrecoverableRollbackError" issue.  Thanks.